# How can I use UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp for scene transitions in Cocos2d?

Tags: ios4, cocos2d-iphone

For a storybook application being developed (with cocos2d-iphone), I am currently using the CCTransitionPageTurn class to handle the transitions between each page's scene. This is dandy and all but I would really like to use UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp transition from the iOS SDK library (much more crispy in my opinion). Here is an example of what I am currently doing:

```
PageThreeScene *pageThreeScene = [PageThreeScene node];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionPageTurn transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:pageThreeScene ]];
```

Does anyone have any recommendations on how I might go implementing scene switches with iPhone SDKs own UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp for transitions between scenes? Would something like that be a big pain? Thanks ahead of time for any input.

Regards,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp to a CCScene because it is not a UIView. And placing CCScene in a UIView wouldn't work because then the scene wouldn't be attached to CCDirector. Plus it wouldn't accept CCScene as a view anyway, because it is not a UIView.

You could (probably) apply the effect to the openGL view of your entire game, but that's not what you want, I know.